# node.js knex mysql terminal warning error

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, knex.js

In my node.js app I use the knex to connect to to mysql db

now I got many of warning messages:

> Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: reconnect. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection

I want to know what can I do to fix it and remove this message

[image]

While looking for result there is a link to the problem here
https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/lib/connection_config.js#L64-L74

Then I found the problem
In heroku the api add  `"?reconnect=true"` to the connection

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-shared-mysql-add-on
this query string create the error.
So now I don't know what needed to be done.

Add the ?"reconnect=true" to the connection like heroku recommend
Or remove this parameter like the warning

Comment: And why don't you show us the code that causes this?

Comment: there must be something with client: 'mysql',  see http://knexjs.org/

Comment: dunno but, `q` and `await` is not needed.

Comment: Try to use mysql driver instead of mysql2 unless you have some good reason to use that.

Comment: I think there is a reason I selected mysql2, not remember now,  I'll try using mysql instead

Comment: I have the same issue. It's super confusing because mysql2 claims that it's 100% compatible with mysql. There is no documentation about the reconnect option… Maybe it makes sense to open a bug report on the mysql2 bug tracker?